# how to create two-dimension list in R

Tags: r, matlab, list, cell, transfer

I want to transfer `matlab code` into R, `ctlist` is a vector, `matlab code` as folllowed:

```
telist{i,j}=ctlist;
[value,number]=max(ctlist);
```

I just wonder there is "data structure" in R like the telist{i,j} in matlab

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can have infinitely nested lists:

```
list1 <- list()

list1[[1]] <- list()

list[[1]][[1]] <- list()
```

and so on...

But for a more practical example, say you want 2 lists having each 3 lists inside:

```
my.list.1 <- list()
my.list.1[[1]] <- list()
my.list.1[[2]] <- list()
my.list.1[[3]] <- list()

my.list.2 <- list()
my.list.2[[1]] <- list()
my.list.2[[2]] <- list()
my.list.2[[3]] <- list()
```

Is there a specific syntax to create those list structures in no time?

As per Richard Skriven's comment, `replicate` can do that. Example: `my.lists <- replicate(n=5, expr=list())` will create 5 lists all at once and store them under the name `my.lists`.

**Filling in the lists**

You could indeed fill in any of those lists or sub-lists with vectors or matrices or arrays. For instance:

```
my.list.1[[1]][[1]] <- c(1,5,3,3,5,3)
my.list.1[[1]][[2]] <- matrix(0, nrow=10, ncol=10)
```

There are no constraints, really.

**Dynamically extending lists**

You could also add dynamically elements to your lists, in loops for instance:

```
my.list <- list() # we're creating a new one, but the following loop could
                  # be using a pre-existing list with data already inside
for(i in 1:10) {
  my.list[[length(my.list) + 1]] <- (i*1):(i*200)
}
```

---

**Arrays**

If however all your data are all of the same type structured in "rectangular/cubic" ways, you can use multidimensional *arrays*.

```
> array(data = NA, dim = c(3,3,3))
, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   NA   NA   NA
[2,]   NA   NA   NA
[3,]   NA   NA   NA

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   NA   NA   NA
[2,]   NA   NA   NA
[3,]   NA   NA   NA

, , 3

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   NA   NA   NA
[2,]   NA   NA   NA
[3,]   NA   NA   NA
```

Comment: Yep, `replicate()` is probably the answer to your last line.

Comment: Is there any data structure , in which I can use `telist[[i]][[j]]<-ctlist`@Dominic Comtois

Comment: Hmmm not sure what would be the structure/content of your `ctlist` object?

Comment: It is just a vector of number

Comment: Are your data all of the same type?

Comment: Yes, it is the same type

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74797/discussion-between-dominic-comtois-and-cheng).